# Replacement for OpenGL deprecated function

Tags: c++, opengl, c++14, glm-math

I'm rewriting a program from OpenGL 2 to OpenGL 3.3 (or higher). I don't exactly how I have to replace the following removed function:

```
glPixelZoom( mScaleX, mScaleY );
```

Should I multiply these 2 values to the projection matrix, like this?:

```
projection = projection * glm::vec2(mScaleX, mScaleY);
```

EDIT:
glDrawPixels is not used at all.  The original code is not mine. Yes, it is removed, not deprecated. Furthermore, I'm replacing

```
glScalef( x/prevX, y/prevY, 1.0f );
```

with

```
model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(x/prevX, y/prevY, 1.0f));
```

and in another function:

```
glTranslatef(posx, -posy, 0 );
```

with:

```
model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(posx, -posy, 0.0f));
```

Since I obtain different results between the old and the new one, I'd like to know if I'm doing it right

Comment: First, it's "removed" not "deprecated". Second, `glPixelZoom` only applies to pixel rectangles drawn by `glDrawPixels`. Since that's removed too, what is your equivalent to this operation?

Comment: Yes, it is removed. I edited my question. glDrawPixels is not used at all

Comment: If your code does neither use `glDrawPixels` nor `glCopyPixels`, then `glPixelZoom` simply did nothing and does not need any replacement.

Comment: Matrix functions (e.g., `glScalef`) in OpenGL accumulate into the current matrix (look for a `glMatrixMode`).  As such, you probably need to use `*=` as compared to `=` in building your matrices.

Comment: @radical7 Do you mean something like this: `model *= glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(x/prevX, y/prevY, 1.0f));`  I have never seen something like this before, are you sure?

Comment: @Luis It looks like `glm` does what I was suggesting when using the functions that take a matrix as its first parameter (as best as I can tell from its documentation).  In this case, I don't think you'll need to use `*=`.  Sorry for the confusion.